# script written inside a page affects in another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have multiple pages that loads inside an div while navigate, the script written inside page 1 overlaps with the script written in page 2. Likewise the script that loaded in previous page also loads in the current page. I use `load()` to load an html page

i have tried `remove()`, `off(click)` but not succeed

`$(document).off('click','.areaClk');
$(document).on('click','.areaClk',function(){

    $(this).addClass('keyenable');
});`

code in page 1 should not works in page2

Comment: this is way too less information

Comment: please add code snippet... so we can help you

Comment: @ParthRaval  $(document).off('click','.areaClk');
$(document).on('click','.areaClk',function(){    
    $(this).addClass('keyenable');
});   i have used this code in page 1 as written inside that page, since i have same name used in page 2 the click works in page 2

Comment: Are you loading new pages with iFrame?

Comment: @PranoySarkar not with iFrames, just inside an div element

Comment: @hariprasath Please update html code snippet

Comment: @PranoySarkar $(document).off('click','.areaClk');
$(document).on('click','.areaClk',function(){    
    $(this).addClass('keyenable');
}); this code is provided in page1 and this should not work in page2

Comment: @hariprasath Please add the code to your question (*edit* the question again).

Comment: Uploading the code snippet will help understanding the problem. Maybe you should limit the scope of the scripts in both sub pages.

Comment: Edit your question and add all necessary information on question itself.Not in comment. Include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

well,you can use "window.location.pathname" to get the current webpage url on which your script is applying.If you dont want your script to apply for a specific page you can do something like below

```
            //here give url where you want your script to apply
             if (window.location.pathname == "localhost/mysite/page1")
           {
            // add script that you want to execute only for specific page 
            alert("applying only  for page 1");
            }
```

Comment: my path would be  the same, just loading the pages inside an div element